# how can we make forms like this with css & html?

Tags: html, css, forms

[image]

now thats a problem :|

Thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: that sure is an ugly form sir. are you sure you want to recreate that or do you want to make it prettier?

Comment: like do you have to copy that form exactly? or make a better design? just askin. it looks ugly as crap for a web form

Comment: well lets say my client love this kinda thing. can we ? :D

Comment: haha good luck with the client then :D anyways i can provide a prototype for that in a jiff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I used it to learn about forms and CSS :)
Thanks @corroded for your comment (there are no more DIVs to be found!)
Tested on FF 4b10, it looks pretty darn close. The code below is what I got after several iterations here.
I'm sure it can be improved (i.e., better reuse of the css classes) but tht's for the answer 3.0 some time in the far away future ;)

The original code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/vSqR3/19/

and to test the new one: http://jsfiddle.net/vSqR3/62/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        .noBullets {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .containerDiv {
            margin-left:0px;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#333;
            border-top-style:none;
            border-right-style:none;
            border-left-style:none;
            border-bottom-style:solid;
            width: 284px;
            height:20px;
        }
        .containerDivNoBorder {
            margin-left:0px;
            border-top-style:none;
            border-right-style:none;
            border-left-style:none;
            border-bottom-style:none;
            width: 284px;
            height:20px;
        }
        .floatingLabel {
            width: 160px;
            height:20px;
            float:left;
            border-style:none;
        }
        .floatingShort {
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#333;
            border-top-style:none;
            border-right-style:none;
            border-left-style:solid;
            border-bottom-style:none;
            width: 39px;
            height:20px;
            float:left;
        }
        .floatingMedium {
            border-top-style:none;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#333;
            border-right-style:none;
            border-left-style:solid;
            border-bottom-style:none;
            width: 80px;
            height:20px;
            float:left;
        }
        .floatingLong {
            border-top-style:none;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#333;
            border-right-style:none;
            border-left-style:solid;
            border-bottom-style:none;
            width: 120px;
            height:20px;
            float:left;
         }
        .floatingLongBorder {
            border-top-style:none;
            border-right-style:none;
            border-left-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#333;
            border-bottom-style:solid;
            width: 120px;
            height:20px;
            float:left;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="send.html">
            <ul class="noBullets">
             <h3>USER ACCOUNT</h3>
               <li class="containerDiv">
                    <label class="floatingLabel">NAME</label>
                    <input class="floatingLong" type="text" name='name'/>
                </li>
                <li class="containerDiv">
                    <label class=floatingLabel>SURNAME</label>
                    <input class=floatingLong type="text" name='surname'/>
                </li>
                <li class="containerDiv">
                    <label class="floatingLabel">BIRTHDAY</label>
                    <input class="floatingShort" type="text" name='bd_d'/>
                    <input class="floatingShort" type="text" name='bd_m'/>
                    <input class="floatingShort" type="text" name='bd_y'/>
                </li>
                <li class="containerDiv">
                    <label class="floatingLabel">GENDER</label>
                    <input class="floatingShort" type="text" name='gender1'/>
                    <input class="floatingMedium" type="text" name='gender2'/>
                </li>
                <li class="containerDiv">
                    <label class="floatingLabel">USERNAME</label>
                    <input class="floatingLong" type="text" name='username'/>
                </li>
                <li class="containerDivNoBorder">
                    <label class="floatingLabel">E-MAIL</label>
                    <input class="floatingLongBorder" type="text" name='email1'/>
                </li>
                <li class="containerDiv">
                    <label class="floatingLabel">RE-TYPE E-MAIL</label>
                    <input class="floatingLong" type="text" name='email2'/>
                </li>
                <li class="containerDivNoBorder">
                    <label class="floatingLabel">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input class="floatingLongBorder" type="password" name='password1'/>
                </li>
                <li class="containerDiv">
                    <label class="floatingLabel">RE-TYPE PASSWORD</label>
                    <input class="floatingLong" type="password" name='password2'/>
                </li>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </ul>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS: Also check out a nicer form here: http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/06/clean-and-pure-css-form-design.html

Comment: you're abusing divs :) try ul or ols for your forms :)

Comment: Sure. As I said above, I used this question to learn and give it a try. What would be the advantage of ul vs div?

Comment: its more semantic that way because you're listing a series of form inputs and labels. divs don't actually describe anything semantically and using a lot just clutters up your markup. here's a link to get you on your way with ditching some extra divs: http://theblog.enova-tech.net/2011/03/divitis-too-much-divs/

Comment: @corroded thanks for the reply. Edited the answer using uls and lis.

Comment: its best not to use breaker for clearing divs and you can not use capital letters :) just another tip :)

Comment: Actually, the breaker is not even needed there. I took it out and for some reason did not save that :/ Also, you mean no capital letters for the markup?

Comment: yup you can just use <li> and <input> like i did

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting guide for you, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
and you can make it more fancier by visiting http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/fancy-form-design-css

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

use uls

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text">
  </li>
</ul>
```

then in your css:

```
label {
  float: left; }

ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

input {  
  border: 0
}
```

a rough sketch but you get the idea