# CSS Form Design Help

Tags: html, css, forms

I have always struggled designing css forms,  I can never get the input and label side by side.  Do you have any words of wisdom that may help me.

I usually use a 10px margin on the bottom but cannot get them aligned

**My Common form**:

```
Name:
Email:
Phone:
Message:
text area
```

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline-block;` or `float: left` the label?

Comment: FWIW, many folks recommend placing labels above fields these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I'm going to get backlash for this from people who think that the only possible way to do things is with pure CSS, divs, spans, etc.  However, your form is tabular.  You have a column of titles, and a column of input fields.  In this case, because of the tabular layout, a valid solution could be tables.....GASP!

Tables are not valid for page layout...let me repeat that again, tables are not valid for layout.  However, you've got an element of a page, you're not doing a full page layout.  You can easily use `<th>` elements to style the labels for the inputs, which is quick and simple.  Overall, the table (tabular) solution would be less verbose than many of the CSS layouts given, which from a pure HTML standpoint is a win.  It will continue to work and layout properly even when the server gets backed up and can't load the external CSS document.  To all those who believe that tables are never ok, let me remind you that this solution will validate with W3 100% of the time provided your table is properly structured.  And it's far more cross browser compatible, with no box-model issues in the "crabby" legacy browers.  Certainly continue to progressively enhance with CSS as is best practice.

Theory and practice, especially in the web world, are two entirely different things.  In theory, all of us should be producing 100% HTML5/CSS3/Semantic/SEO Optimized...blah blah blah.  In practice, theory only goes as far as the first customer complaint.  Progressive enhancement is key to survival.  When a webform breaks in a big corporate setting, money is lost and people get fired.  For that reason, the International Bank I recently did work for had requirements that demanded all its webforms were tabular (assembled with tables)  It's hard to argue with a portfolio of sites whose users generate the company hundreds of millions of $$$ annually.

Comment: That's a valid comment. I don't have anything personal against tables (I know other people do), but it does not answer the question "CSS Form Design Help". I'm guessing Jess is learnign CSS, rather than writing a webform for a multinational company.

Comment: @aleadam, can't fault someone for learning.  But I do think it's important that when someone asks a pointed question that the community offer alternatives if there's a better way to do things.  For instance, if I asked how to properly layout a site with frames, I would hope people in the community wouldn't hesitate to (kindly) offer the alternatives for layout.  That's the beauty of what we do--99.9% of the time, there's not just one way to achieve a goal.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
<div>
  <label for="txtname">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtname" name="txtname"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="txtEmail">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="txtPhone">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtPhone" name="txtPhone"/>
</div>
etc...
```

Then with my CSS:

```
    label { width: 100px; display: inline-block; }
```

Something along those lines.  Nothing fancy, but they are side-by-side and with the surrounding div you get a block level element to give you a line return after each pair.

Comment: forgive my stupidity, but what's the purpose of `<label>` in this example? I know it can be used to enlarge the click area for radio buttons and checkboxes. But here? Just curious. Thank you! :-)

Comment: I have been scolded before for the overuse of DIVs: http://theblog.enova-tech.net/2011/03/divitis-too-much-divs/ Cheers.

Comment: When you use <label> and the 'for' attribute when a user clicks on the label it will set the focus to the corresponding input.  It also allows you to easily style your label text since you can reference it with CSS much easier.

Comment: @Aleadam I wouldn't consider this an overuse.  I see the point of the article you posted, but that is more along the lines of saying use the correct html element for the purpose its designed for instead of using div's for everything.

Comment: So by clicking `Phone:` on your form, my cursor automatically goes to the associated input? Cool. I recognize the easier styling as well, definitely. +1

Comment: Thanks,How would I make all the input fields align?

Comment: @Kyle nice tip. I did not know about the `for` attribute. Does it work inside LI's also?

Comment: @Jess McKenzie probably just easier to show you :) http://jsfiddle.net/KVZnw/1/  In the example I use display: inline-block because <label> are inline elements by default and I need it to stay inline so it doesn't do a return, but inline elements can't have a width so I need it to act like a block level element as well.  HTH

Comment: @Aleadam you have make sure the 'for' attribute of the label and the 'id' attribute of the input are the same for that functionality to work.

Comment: @andrew 'LABEL' is a key part of proper forms design. They are semantic and critical for accessibility. Plus, they offer the usability benefits such as the larger click area as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>

ul.anyclassname{
padding:0;
}

ul.anyclassname li{
list-style-type:none;
clear:left;
}

ul.anyclassname li label{
width:300px;
float:left;
}

.inputs{
float:left;
}

</style>

    <form>
    <ul class="anyclassname">
      <li>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <div div class="inputs"><input type="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
      <label>Email:</label>
      <div div class="inputs"><input type="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
      <label>Phone:</label>
      <div div class="inputs"><input type="text"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: This would work if yo don't need other UL's and LI's. I would suggest using nested classes or two different classes, one for ul and one fo li

Comment: yep. To somebody just starting with CSS changing the style for the markup could be at least puzzling. You never know where that form will need to be.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a complete form in this answer: [how can we make forms like this with css & html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482281/how-can-we-make-forms-like-this-with-css-html/5482535#5482535) . It has the html markups and the css classes you need to start.
The code is also in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vSqR3/64/ (Now with the nice addition of the for attribute, thanks Kyle!)

You will find in that link not only how to put one markup next to the other, but how to set sizes and borders for each.

I strongly suggest you to play on the jsfiddle.net website. You'll be able to modify and test immediately all your changes.